# Change URL on onBeforeRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have following code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {         

    return { redirectUrl: "http://yahoo.com"};
  },
  {
    urls: [
      'http://google.com'
    ],
    types: ['main_frame']
  },
  ['blocking']);
```

This is redirecting google.com to yahoo.com.
My Question is now howto keep `google.com` in the addressbar, showing yahoo.com.

My first attempt was to use

`chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: details.url});`

but that results in an Reloading of the site.

---

**WHY?**

I am requesting this for [pdf.js](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/pdbekdpgndlhjmiobbgcnoagbghfdkfa), since its anoying to loose the PDF URL.

Comment: This is simply not possible. It would also be a huge security issue (imagine `https://evil.com` disguised as `https://mybank.com` )

Comment: Sounds very fishy....

Comment: see my udated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, you may simulate this effect by using a 100%x100% frame - but still, your question sounds very malicious.