# Chrome Extension to Redirect to URL with Parameter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm attempting to create a Chrome extension which will add a parameter to the end of a URL if the URL matches a given pattern (`*://*.mydomain.com/s/*`). Below is the manifest file and background script I have, but I cannot get it working. What am I doing wrong?

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Search Grid View",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Changes MyDomain.com search to grid view by default",

  "background": {
     "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "*://*.mydomain.com/s/*",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ]

}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {         
    var currentUrl = tabs[0].url;
    var newUrl = currentUrl + "&style=gridview"
    return { redirectUrl: newUrl};
  },
  {
    urls: [
      '*://*.mydomain.com/s/*'
    ],
    types: ['main_frame']
  },
  ['blocking']);
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: `browserAction` means an icon in the addressbar (omnibox), see [the API docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction). Otherwise you'd need a background script and [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) or [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API. Clarify the question, please.

Comment: Try "lastFocusedWindow: true" instead of "currentWindow: true"

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! Very new to Chrome extensions, so I've been trying to hack together different examples, which obviously didn't work so well. I've updated the question above and rewritten the structure to use a background page with the webRequest API. That being said, it's still not working. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Try using the code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15359042/3959875) replacing the values accordingly. Thus you'll modify the url *before* it is sent to the server, eliminating the page refresh flicker.

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated my background.js code, but still nothing happens. Take a look at the updated code above. I also added webRequestBlocking  permission to my manifest.json, as I'm pretty sure that's necessary now. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use debugger - click your extension's `background page` on chrome://extensions page and switch to the `Sources` panel.
2. To obtain the url use [onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest)'s callback parameter
3. Check if the url is already modified.

---

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        return {
            redirectUrl: details.url + 
                (details.url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "") +
                (details.url.indexOf("&style=gridview") == -1 ? "&style=gridview" : "")
        };
    },
    {urls: ['*://*.mydomain.com/s/*'], types: ['main_frame']},
    ['blocking']
);
```

Comment: Thank you! The updated code you provided works perfectly. Unfortunately, I have run into one more issue... Now I've realized that sometimes the URL will already have a parameter and sometimes it will not. So, I need to check if there's a "?" in the URL. If there is, I need to append, "&style=gridview", but otherwise I need to append "?style=gridview". What's the best way to go about this? Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: There are many ways to go about it, for example use `indexOf`, see the updated code.